# Inline assembly in GNU C++ compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, inline-assembly, x87

The following inline assemble code is not working on my system.  What is the problem with that code?

If I use `asm` instead of `__asm__` then it works properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float arg1, arg2, div ;

    printf( "Enter two numbers : " );
    scanf( "%f%f", &arg1, &arg2 );

    /* Perform floating Division */


    __asm__ ( "fld %2;"
              "fld %1;"
              "fdiv;"
              "fstp %0;" : "=g" (div) : "g" (arg1), "g" (arg2) ) ;

    printf( "%f / %f = %f\n", arg1, arg2, div );

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Does the source file name end with `.c` or with `.cpp` ? In other words, are you compiling this as C or as C++ ?

Comment: source file name end with .cpp

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: If the extension is .cpp then it is compiled as C++, the title and tag were therefore misleading - edited.

Comment: It compiles fine at https://ideone.com in C, C++ 4.8.1 and C++11 compilation modes.  What error message are you actually getting?  What compiler options have you selected? `asm` is a reserved keyword in ISO C++, but not in ISO C, `__asm__` [should work in both](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html#Alternate-Keywords).  If you use the `-pedantic` option you kind of get what you deserve - nobody likes a pedant!.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a suitable description of any problem. What does it do, what do you expect?

Comment: did you picked a version for your language like `-std=c99` ?

Comment: it compiles fine with tc++ windows .thanks @clifford.

Comment: @LeventeKurusa : You can delete your own comments you know?

Comment: @Atuljssaten : My comment was a request for you to improve the question by adding necessary information - that would be fare more useful that a thanks (I am not even sure what you are thanking me for).  I really hope you are not referring to Turbo C++?